# Warning: Division by zero PHP check

Tags: php, business-logic

I am using symfony 1.1 to read an API and store the values in DB

```
if(($xmlArray->{'MDD'} == 0) || ($xmlArray->{'MDD'} == '0') ){  
       $autoStraObj->setRisk(' - ');
    }else{
       $autoStraObj->setRisk(round(($xmlArray->{'Pips'} / $xmlArray->{'MDD'}), 10));
    }
```

For Some Records, the above code results with

Warning: Division by zero in....
Not sure, that is the issue here

Answer (score 1):

First check `$xmlArray->{'MDD'}` is zero or not.If it is zero for some records then it will give you this error.

```
if(($xmlArray->{'MDD'} != 0) && ($xmlArray->{'MDD'} != ''))
{
   $autoStraObj->setRisk(round(($xmlArray->{'Pips'} / $xmlArray->{'MDD'}), 10));
}
```

Or simply

```
if(!empty( $xmlArray->{'MDD'}) ) {
   $autoStraObj->setRisk(round(($xmlArray->{'Pips'} / $xmlArray->{'MDD'}), 10));
}
```

Or as **cHao**  said try like

```
if (+$xmlArray->{'MDD'} != 0) {
   $autoStraObj->setRisk(round(($xmlArray->{'Pips'} / $xmlArray->{'MDD'}), 10));
}
```

Comment: see `if(($xmlArray->{'MDD'} == 0) || ($xmlArray->{'MDD'} == '0') ){  `

Comment: Note, `empty($xmlArray->{'MDD'})` is false if the value is the string '0.0'.  You might do better to just say `if (+$xmlArray->{'MDD'} != 0)`.

Comment: Then he need to type casting with int

Answer (score 0):

Because for some records `$xmlArray->{'MDD'}` equals zero.

To avoid this - first check if there is a 0 and do not divide, just show "0" instead.

Comment: That appears to be exactly what the script is doing, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for

```
if(empty($xmlArray->{'MDD'})){  
       $autoStraObj->setRisk(' - ');
    }else{
       $autoStraObj->setRisk(round(($xmlArray->{'Pips'} / $xmlArray->{'MDD'}), 10));
    }
```